# passing NSURL and keeping it

Tags: objective-c, webview, uipickerview

I am passing a NSURL from my pickerviewcontroller to my mainviewcontroller. The url is dependent on the user choice in pickerviewcontroller. It works fine, but the user has to repetedly go to the pickerviewcontroller every time the app is restarted to make the choice.

Maybe the code will explain the problem better: This is the pickerviewcontrollers relevant parts...

```
//The save button on the pickerviewcontroller 
- (IBAction)selectedRow:(id)sender {

MainViewController *vc1 = [self.storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"];
vc1.destinationweb =  selectedRow;
[self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Once in MainViewController the destinationweb log shows the address of the user choice in pickerview. But If I turn off the app or go forwards in the app (I have another view controller) and then back to MainViewController - it shows destinationweb = null

This is the MainViewController relevant parts:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

{
    //webView.hidden = YES;
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    NSURL *url = destinationweb;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"destinationweb shows= %@", destinationweb);   
}
[super viewDidLoad];   
}
```

I have no idea what I am supposed to do to make the MainViewController remember the url until another row in picker view is selected??

Comment: save url in user defaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the url string in user defaults and retrieve the url string in view controller

```
- (IBAction)selectedRow:(id)sender 
{
    MainViewController *vc1 = [self.storyboard 
    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview"];
    //Instead of passing it just save the url string in user defaults
    NSString *urlString = [selectedRow absoluteString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:urlString  forKey:@"UserURL"];
    //vc1.destinationweb =  selectedRow;
    [self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    //webView.hidden = YES;
    self.webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *urlString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"UserURL"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString ];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"destinationweb shows= %@", destinationweb);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the value once the app is restarded, you should storage the value (url) in  a file, so when you restart it you can read it from there.